# Can't change src in image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't change the image with jquery: whats going on??

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script text="text/javascript">
$('#caccia').attr('src', '2.png');
</script>

<img id="caccia" src="1.jpg" />

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have not tell your script to wait until the DOM is ready, just write that instead.

```
$(function() {
    $('#caccia').attr('src', '2.png');
});
```

Which is the same as (it can be easier to understand this way).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#caccia').attr('src', '2.png');
});
```

Plus, it's better to have you JavaScript before thz `</body>` http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code within

```
$(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

That way, the script will execute only when all the elements of your DOM have been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change the image, as soon as the page loads:

You can do something like this in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#caccia').attr('src','2.jpg');
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/QJKWK/1/

Comment: You ought to actually explain your answer, not just include a link to a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script text="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#caccia').attr('src', '2.png');
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img id="caccia" src="1.jpg" />
</body>
```